# continuity of convolution function

Tags: analysis

$(f*g)(x)=\displaystyle\int_{\infty} ^{\infty}f(x-t)g(t)dt$.

Let $\chi_{A}$ be the characteristic function on $A$.

I want to show if $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, prove that $f*\chi_{[-1,1]}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt is

$f*\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-t)\chi_{[-1,1]}(t)dt=\int_{-1} ^{1}f(x-t)dt=\int_{x-1} ^{x+1}f(t)dt$.

For convenience, write $f*\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)=g(x)$

Let $\epsilon>0, x_0\in\mathbb{R}.  $ How can I show $|g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$, and fix a sequence $x_n \to x$. Put $g_n:= \chi_{[x_n-1,x_n+1]}$, and note that $g_n \to \chi_{[x-1,x+1]}$ pointwise, so $fg_n\to f\chi_{[x-1,x+1]}$ pointwise. By what you wrote,

$$
f\ast \chi_{[-1,1]}(x_n)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g_n(t)dt
$$

As the integrand is bounded by $f$, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we get that the integral converges to $f\ast \chi_{[-1,1]}$.